# Vuforia Settings for MRTK3

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, target, vuforia, mrtk

I am at a beginner level for Unity applications for Hololens 2 and I have previously made vuforia model target applications using MRTK2. But I couldn't get success to use vuforia with MRTK3 yet.

My expectation is to use vuforia model target behaviour with MRTK3 in unity for HL2 project.

I tried to use the vuforia settings by replacing the camera in the MRTK XR Rig prefab with the AR camera in MRTK3, but it did not work. I added the vuforia behavior component to the camera inside the MRTK XR Rib and tried it, but it still didn't work.

I would be very happy if you could explain what steps should I follow to use vuforia with MRTK3 in my project.

I am really looking forward for your answer. Thank you for your time and interest.

Best, Atakan

Answer (score 1):

For me personally I have not encountered any problems using MRTK3 in combination with Vuforia. However, I have only been working with image targets, just as a heads up. There might be further compatibility issues.
Basically what you wanna do is

1. Attach the Vuforia scripts `VuforiaBehavior` & `DefaultInitializzationErrorHandler` to the main camera under the MRTK XR Rig
2. Set the `Transform` of the `Camera Offset` object under the XR Rig to 0 (positional & rotational coords to 0, scale values to 1)
3. Set the camera y offset value of the `XR Origin` component attached to the `Camera Offset` object to 0 as well

Someone at PTC has been doing the same thing, see [here](https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/66).